# Make discord know input and use it to give output, python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a Discord bot in python 3.5. I want the bot to know when i write ";info @example:1111" and give me output:

- username is:
- user id is:
- user joined at: etc...

I do not get this to work.

This i my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message, user: discord.Member):    
    if message.content.upper().startswith(';INFO'):
        if "248783308341772288" in [role.id for role in message.author.roles]:
            await client.send_message(message.channel,"The users name is: {}".format(user.name))
            await client.send_message(message.channel,"The users ID is: {}".format(user.id))
            await client.send_message(message.channel,"The users status is: {}".format(user.status))
            await client.send_message(message.channel,"The users highest role is: {}".format(user.top_role))
            await client.send_message(message.channel,"The user joined at: {}".format(user.joined_at))
        else:
            print("No access!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to program a command in the `on_message` coroutine.  Instead, use `ext.commands`.  Below I define a command `INFO` that takes a user as an argument.  We use the [`has_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_role) [check](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#checks) to see if the caller has the correct role.  If they don't, there's an error handling coroutine to send them a message.

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=';')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role("ROLE NAME")
async def INFO(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    await bot.send_message(channel,"The users name is: {}".format(user.name))
    await bot.send_message(channel,"The users ID is: {}".format(user.id))
    await bot.send_message(channel,"The users status is: {}".format(user.status))
    await bot.send_message(channel,"The users highest role is: {}".format(user.top_role))
    await bot.send_message(channel,"The user joined at: {}".format(user.joined_at))

@INFO.error
async def info_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Insufficent permission")
```

Comment: Output when i try to run the command (;INFO): Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\solme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'

Comment: @Thomas This is happening because `on_message` is called whenever you receive a message.  The bot does `await bot.on_message(message)` internally, which is failing because your coroutine needs two arguments.  You should probably get rid of `on_message` entirely and break all of your logic out into `@bot.command()` coroutines.

Comment: ok, all other commands in the bot is using on_message but i'l try.

Comment: This make sense, i'll rewrite everything in my bot and stop using on_message. Thank you for your help @Patrick!